# Getting a value from JSON API

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

So as of now I have successfully pulled data from a 3rd party website's API, but I'm still struggling to pull the value out of it. The data is formed in the following way: [image]

My code currently looks somewhat like this:

```
Request.get("url", (error, response, body) => {
             if(error) {
                return console.dir(error);
             }

             console.dir(JSON.parse(body)); 
             var obj = JSON.parse(body);
             var priice = obj.data.items_on_sale.price;
             console.log(priice);
             });
```

So I'd like to pull out the price value but I don't know how to do it correctly. If I remove the last 3 lines I get this: "data: { items_on_sale: [ [Object] ], items_not_on_sale: [] } }", and if I keep it as it is I still can't pull the price value successfully... Any advice?

Comment: The value of items_on_sale cannot be subscripted with price, because it is an array. Which element in the array do you want to inspect for the price? Subscript `items_on_sale[0].price` might yield the value you are looking for.

Comment: obj.data.items_on_sale[0].price is what ur looking for,
inside the items on sale you have Array of Objects.
so that the way u get what ur looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var obj = JSON.parse(body);
var priice = obj.data.items_on_sale[0].price;
console.log(priice);
```

This is what you are looking for.

Comment: :) please choose it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

```
var obj = JSON.parse(body);
var priice = obj.data.items_on_sale[0].price;
console.log(priice);
```

Is the way to go :)